# Displaying text in an expanding div W/CSS3 or JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide

I am trying to make a side nav bar which displays the title but then expands to a more informative link when hovered over. Im not entirely sure that divs are even appropriate here and i have a feeling that JavaScript should be the answer but i am not familiar enough with JavaScript to know which way to go. I've tried messing around with a unordered list thinking that might help but ran into the same issues. any help would be much appreciated,

Here is the JSfiddle (its a very rough version) http://jsfiddle.net/2G5jB/2/

```
           <div id="sidebar">
                <div class="slide">HELP 1<a href="#">'hidden link info'</a></div>
                <div class="slide">HELP 2<a href="#">'hidden link info'</a></div>
                <div class="slide">HELP 3<a href="#">'hidden link info'</a></div>
                <div class="slide">HELP 4<a href="#">'hidden link info'</a></div>
                <div class="slide">HELP 5<a href="#">'hidden link info'</a></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your problem seems to be clear enough, but can you make your question a bit more clear

Answer (score 0):

here is the updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/2G5jB/1/

instead of

```
 a:hover{
      visibility:visible;
 }
```

use

```
  div.slide:hover a{
      visibility:visible;   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because **a** is not visible, it can't be hovered. That's why it does not work for you.

This will do the trick instead!

```
div.slide:hover a {
  visibility:visible;   
}
```